# xdebug.overload_var_dump (setting removed in Xdebug 3) and now?

Tags: php, xdebug, var-dump, xdebug-3

The **xdebug.overload_var_dump** configuration removed in **Xdebug 3**, the documentation shows:

> xdebug.overload_var_dump Has been removed. PHP's var_dump() is now
> always overloaded through xdebug_var_dump() when xdebug.mode is set to
> develop. The xdebug_var_dump() function is available independent of
> which mode is configured.

this configuration has been removed no longer works ...

```
ini_set ('xdebug.overload_var_dump', 1);
```

How do I now, to remove the **var_dump file path** line with **Xdebug 3**?

Comment: By setting `xdebug.mode` to some other value, not "develop"?

Comment: In the previous version it was easy, I'm provisionally solving with CSS  :(
`.xdebug-var-dump>small { display: none; }`